# get UIWebView to load in CGRect correctly

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm trying to get my webView to load correctly in the CGRect frame I set up, with the activityIndicator running.

It kind of loads correctly when I have it set up with `[self.view addSubview:webView];`  but the activityindicator doesnt appear.  When I set it up with `webView.delegate = self;`the activityindicator does appear, but the webview covers up the whole screen when it loads up.  I have a segmentedbar up top that gets covered up then.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect webFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 50.0, 320.0, 318.0);

    activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];
    activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(250, 250, 30.0, 30.0);
    self.view.center = CGPointMake(160.0f, 190.0f);
    activityIndicator.center = self.view.center;

    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];

    [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
    webView.delegate = self;
//  [self.view addSubview:webView]; 
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"activity started");
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
}
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"activity stopped");
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    self.view = webView;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"activity stopped");
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    [[self view]  addSubView:webView];
}
```

The views weren't being covered, they were being removed from the hierarchy by resetting the view property.